# Usage of Do vs. Did

Tags: tenses

My girlfriend and I are arguing on what is the correct way of writing the following sentence. To provide a little context - The children have never met their Grandmother yet. Is it correct to say:

> They had never known their grandmother and it was high time they did.

or

> They had never known their grandmother and it was high time they do.

I'm confused because for me the first one *sounds* correct but she argues that the latter is correct since we're talking in the present tense.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence is fine if you’re talking about a past situation. If you’re talking about the present situation, then you need to say

> They **have** never known their grandmother and it **is**
>   high time they **did**.

It’s *did* in both cases, because one of the uses of the past tense is to express what is known as ‘unreal meaning’. You can’t use *do*, because it clearly isn’t yet true that the children know their grandmother.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Though I only thought it _sounded_ correct, I now have an explanation to go with it.

Comment: *Do* can be used in the second to represent the implied future.

Comment: I would suggest that it is high time that government reconsidered how it is going to deal with drug pushers, for current methods are expensive, fundamentally ineffective and deny funding in far more needy areas.

Example sentence in Oxford Dictionary
Why did they use past tense "considered"? It said "... it IS high time that .."!  @VincentPaca

Answer (score 1):

In this context, I think the first sentence is correct.

`They had never known their grandmother and it was high time they did.`

Since the sentence starts with `They HAD ..`, maintaining the same tense through out, it should end with `.. they DID`.
However, if it starts with `They HAVE never ..`, then using `..it IS high time they DO` makes sense.